# Newrelic configuration not being read from the newrelic.ts on Nrwl Nx NestJs

Tags: typescript, nestjs, newrelic

I have an issue where my newrelic configuration is not being read by my NestJs app. Just an extra info, my NestJs app is part of a `Nrwl Nx` monorepo.

`newrelic.ts` is in the same folder as the `main.ts`

[image: Newrelic ts in same folder as main ts]

Error thrown was:

```
Error: New Relic requires that you name this application!
Set app_name in your newrelic.js file or set environment variable
NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME. Not starting!
```

I did install `"newrelic": "9.0.3",`

I also tried to initiate `newrelic` before the rest of application gets bootstrapped by calling the require on the top of `main.ts`

```
// @ts-ignore
const newrelic = require('newrelic');

import { INestApplication, Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { NewrelicInterceptor } from './app/interceptors/newrelic.interceptor';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.enableCors({
    origin: process.env.CORS_ORIGIN?.split(','),
    credentials: true,
  });
  setupNewRelicInterceptor(app);
  const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
  await app.listen(port);
  Logger.log(` Application is running on: http://localhost:${port}`);
}

function setupNewRelicInterceptor(app: INestApplication) {
  app.useGlobalInterceptors(new NewrelicInterceptor());
  Logger.log(`New Relic Interceptor Added`);
}

bootstrap();
```

If I pass the configuration as environment variables, it works, but that is not what I intended to do at the moment.

Really appreciate the help if anyone can point out where the issue is.
Cheers!

Comment: For Nestjs monorepo, I faced the exact issue. I placed the `newrelic.js` [`not newrelic.ts`] file in the root directory [to the most directory of the project] and the issue was resolved. Try this and comment here about the result!

Answer (score 0):

For Nestjs monorepo, I faced the exact issue. I placed the newrelic.js [not newrelic.ts] file in the root directory [to the most directory of the project] and the issue was resolved. Try this and comment here about the result!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue with multiple Nest.js services in an Nx monorepo. I wanted different New Relic configurations for the different services, so having the `newrelic.js` file in the root of the monorepo was not an option for me. What I ended up doing was making use of Nx's cascading environment variables functionality and setting the `NEW_RELIC_NO_CONFIG_FILE` New Relic env var to `true` so it does not require the `newrelic.js` config file.

The env vars shared between all services, like the `NEW_RELIC_LICENSE_KEY` I put in the `.env` file in the root directory and then inside each app's root directory, I put the service-specific variables, like `NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME` and `NEW_RELIC_LABELS`.